# Parameter suggestion for custom functions in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to get IntelliSense to display me the parameters of my custom function within my php file?
It seems to be working with other languages [image: Link]
<sub>(source: [telerik.com](https://developer.telerik.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ParameterHelp-1024x576.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Same problem, some news about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of right now this is not possible natively. <s>Even the popular [PHP IntelliSense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense) extension does not support this.</s>

***Edit***: It seems that the PHP IntelliSense extension has now been updated to support Signature help as well:

I have recently discovered an extension called [PHP Intelephense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) which can do exactly this.

[image]

You can even utilize [Type Declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) and PHP 7 [Return Type Declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration) to empower it even more:

[image]

The best result is when all type declarations are combined with a DocString, which allows you to write descriptions of parameters. I use the [PHP DocBlocker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neilbrayfield.php-docblocker) extension to write these, but you could use another, or write them manually.

[image]